# Does ANDROID_ID comes under any privacy protection or consent rules?

Tags: android, privacy, gdprconsentform, android-identifiers

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID

Not to be confused with Android Advertising id,
Does the **ANDROID_ID** as mentioned in above link
**comes under GDPR or similar laws as personally identifiable data?**

Can I use this to keep track of unique devices without coming under any GDPR policy requirements or any other privacy laws?